# Performant async I/O for relational databases

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, rdbms, postgresql-performance

We are trying to optimize our database requests and also reduce the number of database connections in our Node.js servers to Postgres database.

Do Redis database drivers and Redis database connections perform better than relational database drivers/connections in Node.js? I hear tales of needing more database connections for a relational database. My experience with Redis is that just a few connections will suffice, for a given Node.js server process, no matter the load on the server.

With async I/O, can connections be reused, or perhaps the same DB connection used for multiple queries/requests in parallel? Does it differ between database vendors?

Does anyone have recommendation as far as the best possible database connection library for Node.js + Postgres in terms of performance

Comment: There are multiple performant modules, search on npmjs.com or node-modules.com and then check the docs for 'connection pooling'.  But as far as the actual performance its impossible to really say without getting into any actual scenario.  Also you asked like three reallly broad questions so someone may try to close your question.

Comment: Simply by selecting the library won't be enough to achieve good performance. You would need to follow all the right implementation patterns to get there. In terms of ultimately flexibility, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it will let you do anything you want, and to continue fine-tuning your app's performance to any extent.